Single string argument seen as multiple arguments
I am kind of new to python and have recently been working on writing a python script to automate a game via emulators and for that I have been using threading. Now I wanted to make some changes to a function and suddenly I get an error message from the thread that 13 arguments were given instead of the required 1.
The original code goes along the following lines:
def go_to_main_coords(device, main_coords):
    click(device, (9, 908))
    click(device, (9, 908))
    go_to_coords(device, main_coords)


main_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_coords, args=(main_device, support_coords))
support_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_main_coords, args=(support_device, main_coords))
#Start threads
main_thread.start()
support_thread.start()

#going to coords
main_thread.join()

This worked perfectly fine. The issue started appearing after I changed the go_to_main_coords() function to speed up this step which gets called quite a few times.
After the changes the relevant code looked as follows:
def go_to_main_coords(device):
    click(device, (9, 908))
    click(device, (9, 908))
    click(device, (40, 820))
    click(device, (260, 800))
    click(device, (270, 400))

main_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_coords, args=(main_device, support_coords))
support_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_main_coords, args=(support_device))
# Start threads
main_thread.start()
support_thread.start()

# going to coords
main_thread.join()

When running the version of the script I now get the following message once the code arrives at this part:

TypeError: go_to_main_coords() takes 1 positional argument but 13 were given

Why I think this issue has to do with the string itself and the processing of it is because  the variable support_device passed on to the function go_to_main_coords() is a string such as "emulator-5564" which fits the exact number of "arguments" that are apparently given. If the program continues to run the support_device eventually changes to something along the lines of "localhost:5595" and the error message then says 14 arguments were given which again lines up with the number of characters in the string.
My question now is, why does it work when giving the function 2 arguments but not with just one. I even tried running it where go_to_main_coords() requires 2 arguments but the second one is just ignored. That works as well. Yet once I remove the second argument from both the call as well as the definition it keeps giving me this error.

Why are you threading go_to_coords when you're calling it directly in go_to_main_coords?  Maybe you should explain exactly what you're hoping to achieve

Something along the way is unpacking the object given to args. In the first case, that is a 2 element tuple of (main_device, support_coords) that gets correctly unpacked into two objects.. In the second, that's NOT a 1-element tuple - (support_device) is the same as if the parentheneses weren't there - support_device which then is tried to be unpacked - in case of a string that means going character by character. In order to have 1-element tuple, you should use (support_device,) - note the comma.

@SIGHUP what I'm doing is grabbing coordinates for something I want to rally in my game on one emulator and then moving to those coordinates which are always different on my main account (go_to_coords) while my main then moves to those coords I want the second account to center back onto my main account on the map (go_to_main_coords) which is a fixed position and therefor can use a functionality in the game that is quicker than what i need to do for go_to_coords.  matszwecja and Thomas have already solved the issue though so I appreciate the help.

support_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_main_coords, args=(support_device))

The args is supposed to be a tuple of arguments. Since there is only one argument now, the parentheses are not interpreted as a tuple but just as precedence override, like in (1 + 2) * 3. Add a trailing comma to fix this:
support_thread = threading.Thread(target=go_to_main_coords, args=(support_device,))

See e.g. TupleSyntax on the Python wiki.

Thanks! That fixed the issue! Also thank you to @matszwecja who answered the same thing. I did not know about this behaviour. I appreciate the quick help.
